# Map routes funciona somente o padrão

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estou tendo um problema no meu projeto. Tenho duas rotas, a "Default" e uma de teste, mas não sei se está feito corretamente pois não funciona quando colocam na url o que coloquei ali, funciona somente o "Default"

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "TestRoute",
            "{id}",
            new { controller = "Inicio", action = "Inicio", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { id = @"\d+" } //one or more digits only, no alphabetical characters
        );
        //default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Inicio", action = "Inicio", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suas duas rotas estão apontando para o mesmo `Controller` e `Action`.

Veja o seguinte modelo de mapeamento de rota que encontrei nessa pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272625/asp-mvc-route-config-the-resource-cannot-be-found-error)

```
   context.MapRoute(
                "Comment_default",
                "Comment/PostMsg",
                new { controller = "Comment", action = "PostMsg", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Demo.Web.Controllers" }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "Comment_default",
                "Comment/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Demo.Web.Areas.Comment.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: Qualquer tipo de rota que eu crio (mesmo tirando a default) só funciona a página quando eu chamo {controller}/{action}